# Xstream or Jaxb schema support

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xstream

I have xml like this

```
<abc:city>
  <def:cityname />
  <xyz:postalTown>
     Sacramento
  </xyz:postalTown>
</abc:city>

<abc:city>
  <def:cityname />
  <pqr:postalTown>
     Sacramento
  </pqr:postalTown>
</abc:city>
```

Can xstream handle these namespaces like 'abc' in `<abc:city>`

Also namespace for `<pqr:postalTown>` can be changed as I am unaware of the response coming. How can this be handled dynamically through xstream.

If this is impossible in xstream; can it be handled using jaxb?

EDIT:
My class will be City:

```
Class City{
String cityName;
String postalTown;
}
```

How can I map above xml to **City** class as tags contain prefixes?

Comment: Do the prefixes correspond to namespace declarations, or do you have element named that just happen to have the colon character in them?

Comment: prefixes correspond to namespace declarations

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

If the prefixes do not correspond to namespace declarations, then you could use the approach from the answer I linked below from a related question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11970622/383861

---

**NOTE ABOUT NAMESPACE QUALIFICATION**

The prefixes used don't come into play in terms of object-to-XML mapping.  As long as the the `xyz` and `pqr` prefixes correspond to the same namespace you will be fine with any object-to-XML solution that supports namespaces.

Even though the following documents contain different prefixes they have the same namespace qualification.

**Document #1**

```
<abc:city xmlns:abc="ABC" xmlns:def="DEF" xmlns:ghi="XYZ">
    <def:cityName/>
    <ghi:postalTown>
        Sacramento
    </ghi:postalTown>
</abc:city>
```

**Document #2**

```
<jkl:city xmlns:jkl="ABC" xmlns:mno="DEF" xmlns:pqr="XYZ">
    <mno:cityName/>
    <pqr:postalTown>
        Sacramento
    </pqr:postalTown>
</jkl:city>
```

---

**JAXB AND NAMESPACES**

Below is how you would map your `City` class to the XML documents above.  Note how it is the namespace URI and not the prefix that is specified on the `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement` annotations.

```
package forum11932402;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(namespace="ABC")
public class City {

    @XmlElement(namespace="DEF")
    String cityName;

    @XmlElement(namespace="XYZ")
    String postalTown;

}
```

Below is some information on JAXB and namespaces:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

---

**DEMO CODE**

The following demo code can be used to unmarshal either of the XML documents I have posted earlier in this answer.

```
package forum11932402;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(City.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum11932402/input.xml");
        City city = (City) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(city, System.out);
    }

}
```

Below is the output from running the demo code.  The JAXB implementation has assigned new prefixes.  The `cityName` element is still namespace qualified, it just corresponds to the default namespace which was declared as `xmls="DEF"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:city xmlns="DEF" xmlns:ns2="XYZ" xmlns:ns3="ABC">
    <cityName></cityName>
    <ns2:postalTown>
        Sacramento
    </ns2:postalTown>
</ns3:city>
```

Comment: I guess both JAXB 2 and XStream can handle namespaces.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda - JAXB (JSR-222) implementations definitely do.  XStream has some, see the "Why does XStream not have any namespace support?" section in the XStream FAQ:  http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html#XML

Comment: True, for XStream you need to set up Stax driver instead of default DOM driver. However I'd still recomend using JAXB for XML<->POJO mapping as long as you don't need XStream specific features.

Comment: Question is: How can I map '</pqr:postalTown>' to class?

Comment: @imrantariq - I don't follow your last comment.  If your question

Comment: @imrantariq - If you are interested in how to map an object to that XML could you post what you would like your classes to look like?

Comment: @imrantariq - I have updated my answer based on your updates.