# How to make JAXB unmarshaller to ignore prefixes?

Tags: namespaces, jaxb, prefix, unmarshalling

I have the following XML:

```
<ns2:Person name="John" age="20" />
```

And I want to unmarshal it to JAXB object Person which was generated from the XSD.

this is the code I'm running:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PersoEntity.class);
Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
Person p = (Person)um.unmarshal(sr);
```

Surprisingly I get the following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "ns2" for element "ns2:Person" is not bound.]
```

How do I solve it? Thanks

Comment: you only posted one xml tag... is this really your case, i.e you want to unmarshall just this segment (or there's a whole xml document, which should have xmlns:ns2 defined) ?

Comment: you guessed right, only this segment is what I want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**GETTING THE FRAGMENT**

The way that you are currently getting the XML fragment is causing the namespace declarations to be lost.  In your fragment `ns2` is no longer a prefix, you just have a element name with a colon in it (`ns2:Person`).  This is going to cause problems with namespace aware parsers.  The article below may be a better approach for you to get the XML fragment:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

**HANDLING YOUR USE CASE**

Using the XML fragment that you have, you could create an `XMLFilter` that removes the prefix from the XML element, and then leverage JAXB's `UnmarshallerHandler` to do the unmarshalling.

***Demo***

```java
package forum11968399;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl;

public class Demo {

    private static final String xml = "<ns2:Person name='John' age='20' />";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlReader = sp.getXMLReader();
        XMLFilter xmlFilter = new MyXMLFilter(xmlReader);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PersonEntity.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = um.getUnmarshallerHandler();
        xmlFilter.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
        xmlFilter.parse(new InputSource(sr));
        PersonEntity p = (PersonEntity) unmarshallerHandler.getResult();
    }

    private static class MyXMLFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {

        public MyXMLFilter(XMLReader xmlReader) {
            super(xmlReader);
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            int colonIndex = qName.indexOf(':');
            if(colonIndex >= 0) {
                qName = qName.substring(colonIndex + 1);
            }
uri = XML_NAMESPACE; //to prevent unknown XML element exception, we have to specify the namespace here
            super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                throws SAXException {
            int colonIndex = qName.indexOf(':');
            if(colonIndex >= 0) {
                qName = qName.substring(colonIndex + 1);
            }
            super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        }

    }

}
```

***PersonEntity***

```java
package forum11968399;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PersonEntity {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    private int age;

}
```

Comment: your solution almost worked. I had to modify it a bit. Even though we got rid of the prefix, I still got an exception of an unknown XML element due to namespace issues. So I just put the namespace in the Uri variable and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to nest the desired element inside another element that binds the namespace. It doesn't really matter what you bind it to, just make it a valid XML document that will parse. Then you can [unmarshal by declared type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalByDeclaredType)

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
String xml = "<ns2:Person name=\"John\" age=\"20\" />";
String xmlWithPrefixMapped = "<ns2:FakeElement xmlns:ns2=\"someuri\">" + xml + "</ns2:FakeElement>";
StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlWithPrefixMapped);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(sr));
Node n = (Node) doc.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild();
JAXBElement<Person> personElement = um.unmarshal(n, Person.class);
Person p = personElement.getValue();
```

Comment: I get the following:
The method unmarshal(Node, Class<T>) in the type Unmarshaller is not applicable for the arguments (Element, Class<Person>)

Comment: This worked for me, although instead of nesting it inside a new element, I just added the namespace info into the top-level tag I was getting.