# JAXB unmarshalling of "generic" real world documents

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

We have a large set of configuration documents of the style

```
<foo>
  <bar class="com.diedel.Gnarf">
    ...more content
  </bar>
  <bar class="de.doedel.Bork">
    ..more content
  </bar>
  ...
</foo>
```

The generic implementation classes are all  mapped using Jaxb themselves.

Before i finally revert to Xstream, a question to the community: Is there a (non hack) way to get this unmarshalled in Jaxb. What we tried so far is "nested" unmarshalling using an @XMLAdapter, where the "bar" field gets an Element, gets the target class and calls another "unmarshall" cycle. This approach has been a) quite slow and b) is broken with the switch to Java 7 where some magic ThreadLocal destroys the context when returning from the inner unmarshall.

I found that MOXy may support this using @XmlDiscriminatorNode - this looks like a good solution and i really like the very good input of Blaise - but adding a >7MB lib just for fun is not an option.

Other ideas?

Comment: MOXy's `@XmlDescriminatorNode` extension is useful for mapping inheritance relationships (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html).  The install footprint for MOXy is smaller if use the bundles instead of the entire `eclipselink.jar` which also contains JPA and SDO implementations. I'm personally working reducing the footprint further, you can track my progress using the following bug:  http://bugs.eclipse.org/384399

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like the following with [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) and [**StAX (JSR-173)**](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=173):

**Demo**

A StAX `XMLStreamReader` can be used to parse the XML document.  You can use it to advance to a `bar` element, then you can read the `class` attribute and load the appropriate Java class from a `ClassLoader`.  Then you can leverage one of the `unmarshal` methods that takes a class parameter.

```
package forum12402215;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Bork.class.getClassLoader();
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bork.class, Gnarf.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("src/forum12402215/input.xml");
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);
        xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to "foo" element
        xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to "bar" element

        while(xsr.getLocalName().equals("bar")) {
             String className = xsr.getAttributeValue("", "class");
             Class<?> clazz = classLoader.loadClass(className);
             Object object = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, clazz).getValue();
             System.out.println(object);
             xsr.nextTag();
        }
    }

}
```

**Bork**

Below is a sample `Bork` class.

```
package forum12402215;

public class Bork {

    private String b;

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bork(b=" + b + ")";
    }

}
```

**Gnarf**

Below is a sample `Gnarf` class:

```
package forum12402215;

public class Gnarf {

    private int a;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Gnarf(a=" + a + ")";
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

Below is he sample document I used used for this example based on the one from your question.  I changed the package names.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <bar class="forum12402215.Gnarf">
        <a>123</a>
    </bar>
    <bar class="forum12402215.Bork">
        <b>Hello World</b>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.

```
Gnarf(a=123)
Bork(b=Hello World)
```

Comment: Again, thanks for the quick and very detailed response. That said, i must add that a generic way is really needed. For one, <foo> is more complex and attributes are marshalled on it, too. Second, "generic" instantiations are at many places and any nesting depth. But your answer points to another option: I should be able to do this using a sax filter that maps class="x.y.Z" to xsi:type="Z"?

Comment: @mtraut - Yes you could use a SAX filter.  Here is a link to one of my answers that may help with that approach:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11970622/383861

Comment: Hmmm, i will give this a try (while it still has the hack flavor). Is there a simple way to keep the fully qualified class names alive?

Comment: I will give this the answer the reward, even so i recognize the nearly identical advice from @Ian. But you always invest a lot of work. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

If the structure really is that simple I'd be tempted to parse the top two levels (foo and the class attribute of bar) myself using an `XMLStreamReader`, then hand the reader off to the JAXB unmarshaller to parse each bar, assembling the results into a list. I wouldn't bother trying to parse the outer envelope layers using JAXB directly.

Comment: +1 - You got your answer in before mine.  If you're curious what the impl of this approach would look like, check out:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12402813/383861

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. As your answer is very similiar to @Blaise one, i will only comment once....