# JAXB dont want wrapping class

Tags: xml, jaxb, jaxb2

Below is the xml I have to work with:

```
<watermarks identifier="X" hostname="X">
   <watermark type="XX" value="1234"/>
   <watermark type="YY" value="1234" />
</watermarks>
```

I just want to get a list of Watermark objects using JAXB without creating a new Watermarks class. Is it possible or should I have to create a Watermarks class which contains a list of Watermark objects ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [**StAX (JSR-173)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=173) `XMLStreamReader` to parse the XML document (an implementation is included in the JDK/JRE since Java SE 6). Then you could advance it to advance to each `watermark` element and then have [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) unmarshal that.

**Demo**

Assuming the `Watermark` class is annotated with `@XmlRootElement` you could do the following.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Watermark.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("input.xml");
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);
        xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to "watermarks" element
        xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to "watermark" element

        while(xsr.getLocalName().equals("watermark")) {
             Watermark object = (Watermark) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
             System.out.println(object);
             xsr.nextTag();
        }
    }

}
```

**Full Example**

- [JAXB unmarshalling of "generic" real world documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402215/jaxb-unmarshalling-of-generic-real-world-documents/12402813#12402813)

**Generic List Wrapper Class**

In my answer to the question below I provided an example of a generic list wrapper class that you may find useful.

- [How to marshalling the muliptle object using jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323397/how-to-marshalling-the-muliptle-object-using-jaxb/12323657#12323657)