# How to loop on multiple xml files with jaxb

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have an application who create some temporary XML that I have to parse and catch some information in. 
One of theses XML contains multiples rows with path to each related XML. 
It's something like :

```
<z:row TimeStamp="2012-09-25T09:58:49" FileName="\\test\app\myfile_AB.xml"/>
<z:row TimeStamp="2012-09-25T09:58:49" FileName="\\test\app\myfile_CD.xml"/>
...
```

I would like to know if it's possible to parse this "master" XML with JAXB, get all the path and then do a loop and treat each of the related XMLs in one single operation.

All the XML have approximately the same structure.

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is possible. You have to define 2 separate XSDs first. one is master XSD for master file & then second XSD for other all files. Below is one suggested XML structure for master XML

```
  <files>
      <z:row>
      <z:row>
      <z:row>
      .
      .
  <files>
```

Auto Generate java pojo classes for both XSDs. Then whenever you receive master XML, first unmarshall it using auto-generated class for master XSD. Here you will get object corresponding to root elemente e.g Files.java object. Now in this files object iterate over row objects & get FileName. Now for each FileName, again create separate unmarshaller & unmarshall that file with its auto-generated class.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend parsing the outer document using a [**StAX (JSR-173)**](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=173) `XMLStreamReader`.  The as you advance to each `row` element I would have the [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation unmarshal the content.  This eliminates the need to holding the entire outer document in memory.

**Example Demonstrating the Concept**

- [JAXB unmarshalling of "generic" real world documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402215/jaxb-unmarshalling-of-generic-real-world-documents/12402813#12402813)