# Reading in a list of Elements that have different names, but are the same type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm attempting to add JAXB annotations to a class in order to unmarshal XML that looks similar to this(note I will not need to marshal a java bean into XML...):

```
    <fixture_statistics id="3812596">
      <home_team_stats id="2">
        <id>2</id>
        <tackles>58</tackles>
        <possession>1868</possession>
        <territory>2603</territory>
        <minutes_in_22>1316</minutes_in_22>
        ...
      </home_team_stats>
      <guest_team_stats id="21061">
        <id>21061</id>
        <tackles>20</tackles>
        <possession>3114</possession>
        <territory>2379</territory>
        <minutes_in_22>1171</minutes_in_22>
        ...
      </guest_team_stats>
      <home_player_1 id="2306143" teamid="2">
        <id>2306143</id>
        <tackles>3</tackles>
        <metres_gained>38</metres_gained>
        ...
      </home_player_1>
      <home_player_1 id="2306143" teamid="2">
        <id>2306143</id>
        <tackles>3</tackles>
        <metres_gained>38</metres_gained>
        ...
      </home_player_1>
      <home_player_1 id="2306143" teamid="2">
        <id>2306143</id>
        <tackles>3</tackles>
        <metres_gained>38</metres_gained>
        ...
      </home_player_1>
      ...
      <guest_player_1 id="2306143" teamid="2">
        <id>2306143</id>
        <tackles>3</tackles>
        <metres_gained>38</metres_gained>
        ...
      </guest_player_1>
      <guest_player_2 id="2306143" teamid="2">
        <id>2306143</id>
        <tackles>3</tackles>
        <metres_gained>38</metres_gained>
        ...
      </guest_player_2>
      <guest_player_3 id="2306143" teamid="2">
        <id>2306143</id>
        <tackles>3</tackles>
        <metres_gained>38</metres_gained>
        ...
      </guest_player_3>
      ...
</fixture_statistics>
```

* Note disregard some of the element values as I copied and pasted for this question...

I have managed to map the "fixture_statistics", "home_team_stats" and "guest_team_stats" elements to their respective classes, and I am able to correctly unmarshal those elements, but I am having an issue with the "home_player_n" and the "guest_player_n" elements.  I have created a class that contains the properties that are found within those elements, but I do not know how to handle the fact that the elements have different names - "home_player_1" up to "home_player_22" and the same for guest players.

Here is a sample of my fixture statistics class, and my fixture player statistics class so that someone can point out where I am going wrong...

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "fixture_statistics")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FixtureStatistics {

    private Collection<FixturePlayerStatistics> homeTeamPlayerStatistics = new ArrayList<>();

    private Collection<FixturePlayerStatistics> guestTeamPlayerStatistics = new ArrayList<>();
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FixturePlayerStatistics {
    @XmlElement(name="id")
    private Long playerId;
    private Integer tackles;
    @XmlElement(name="metres_gained")
    private Integer metresGained;
}
```

On the FixturePlayerStatistics class I can't add an XMlRootElement annotation, since the element could be 1 of 44 strings, also I have temporarily removed any annotations from the collections in the FixtureStatistics class, since I am honestly not sure what goes there.  I have tried using @XmlElementRef, designating all the possible element names, but that hasn't worked for me yet, also the XML cannot be changed, and I dont have a schema to work with, only the resulting XML from an API call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some different options to support this use case.  But in general I would recommend avoiding situations where an index is worked into an element name.

**OPTION #1 - SEPARATE FIELDS/PROPERTIES**

One way to handle this use case is to have a separate field/property for each of the 22 guest and 22 home players.

```
package forum13219778;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "fixture_statistics")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FixtureStatistics {

    FixturePlayerStatistics guest_player_1;
    FixturePlayerStatistics guest_player_2;
    FixturePlayerStatistics guest_player_3;
    ...
    FixturePlayerStatistics guest_player_22;

    FixturePlayerStatistics home_player_1;
    FixturePlayerStatistics home_player_2;
    FixturePlayerStatistics home_player_3;
    ...
    FixturePlayerStatistics home_player_22;     
}
```

---

**OPTION #2 - USE A SAX`XMLFilter` to STRIP OFF _# SUFFIX**

If your use case only deals with unmarshalling then you could use a SAX `XMLFilter` to strip off the unique suffix on each element and in your JAXB annotations simply map to `home_player` and `guest_player`.  For an `XMLFilter` example see:

- [How to make JAXB unmarshaller to ignore prefixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968399/how-to-make-jaxb-unmarshaller-to-ignore-prefixes/11970622#11970622)

---

**OPTION #3 - USE `@XmlElementRefs` and an `ObjectFactory`**

***FixtureStatistics***

To use the `@XmlElementRefs`/`@XmlElementRef` annotations you will need to change your collections to hold instances of `JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics>`.  The `JAXBElement` will be used to hold the element name information.

```
package forum13219778;

import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "fixture_statistics")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FixtureStatistics {

    @XmlElementRefs({ 
        @XmlElementRef(name="home_player_1"),
        @XmlElementRef(name="home_player_2"),
        @XmlElementRef(name="home_player_3")
    })
    private Collection<JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics>> homeTeamPlayerStatistics = new ArrayList<>();

    @XmlElementRefs({ 
        @XmlElementRef(name="guest_player_1"),
        @XmlElementRef(name="guest_player_2"),
        @XmlElementRef(name="guest_player_3")
    })
    private Collection<JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics>> guestTeamPlayerStatistics = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

***ObjectFactory***

In combination with `@XmlElementRef` you need to declare the root elements using the `@XmlElementDecl` annotation.  This is done via an object factory class annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.

```
package forum13219778;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "home_player_1")
    public JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics> createHomePlayer1(FixturePlayerStatistics player) {
        return new JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics>(new QName("home_player_1"), FixturePlayerStatistics.class, player);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "home_player_2")
    public JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics> createHomePlayer2(FixturePlayerStatistics player) {
        return new JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics>(new QName("home_player_2"), FixturePlayerStatistics.class, player);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "home_player_3")
    public JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics> createHomePlayer3(FixturePlayerStatistics player) {
        return new JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics>(new QName("home_player_3"), FixturePlayerStatistics.class, player);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "guest_player_1")
    public JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics> createGuestPlayer1(FixturePlayerStatistics player) {
        return new JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics>(new QName("guest_player_1"), FixturePlayerStatistics.class, player);
    }


    @XmlElementDecl(name = "guest_player_2")
    public JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics> createGuestPlayer2(FixturePlayerStatistics player) {
        return new JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics>(new QName("guest_player_2"), FixturePlayerStatistics.class, player);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "guest_player_3")
    public JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics> createGuestPlayer3(FixturePlayerStatistics player) {
        return new JAXBElement<FixturePlayerStatistics>(new QName("guest_player_3"), FixturePlayerStatistics.class, player);
    }

}
```

***Demo***

```
package forum13219778;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(FixtureStatistics.class, ObjectFactory.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum13219778/input.xml");
        FixtureStatistics fs = (FixtureStatistics) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(fs,  System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Blaise.  

Just out of interest I went with option 1 since I could actually make use of separate objects, as well as getting them all in a collection, later on.