# JAXB XML Prefix Issue

Tags: jaxb, pojo, prefix

I have an input xml file of below one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cxp:exportedDefect xmlns:cxp="http://export.coverity.com/v7">
    <user>admin</user>
    <project>tev</project>
    <timeStamp>2014-05-23T08:45:08.916+03:00</timeStamp>
    <cxp:mergedDefect>
        <checkerName>FORWARD_NULL</checkerName>
        <checkerSubcategory>deref_constant_null</checkerSubcategory>
        <cid>10549</cid>
        <componentName>Default.Other</componentName>
        <defectStateAttributeValues>
            <attributeDefinitionId>
                <name>DefectStatus</name>
            </attributeDefinitionId>
            <attributeValueId>
                <name>Dismissed</name>
            </attributeValueId>
        </defectStateAttributeValues>
        <defectStateAttributeValues>
            <attributeDefinitionId>
                <name>Classification</name>
            </attributeDefinitionId>
            <attributeValueId>
                <name>False Positive</name>
            </attributeValueId>
        </defectStateAttributeValues>
        <defectStateAttributeValues>
            <attributeDefinitionId>
                <name>Action</name>
            </attributeDefinitionId>
            <attributeValueId>
                <name>Undecided</name>
            </attributeValueId>
        </defectStateAttributeValues>
        <defectStateAttributeValues>
            <attributeDefinitionId>
                <name>Severity</name>
            </attributeDefinitionId>
            <attributeValueId>
                <name>Unspecified</name>
            </attributeValueId>
        </defectStateAttributeValues>
        <defectStateAttributeValues>
            <attributeDefinitionId>
                <name>Fix Target</name>
            </attributeDefinitionId>
            <attributeValueId>
                <name>Untargeted</name>
            </attributeValueId>
        </defectStateAttributeValues>
        <defectStateAttributeValues>
            <attributeDefinitionId>
                <name>Legacy</name>
            </attributeDefinitionId>
            <attributeValueId>
                <name>False</name>
            </attributeValueId>
        </defectStateAttributeValues>
        <defectStateAttributeValues>
            <attributeDefinitionId>
                <name>Owner</name>
            </attributeDefinitionId>
            <attributeValueId>
                <name>Unassigned</name>
            </attributeValueId>
        </defectStateAttributeValues>
        <defectStateAttributeValues>
            <attributeDefinitionId>
                <name>TranslatedOwner</name>
            </attributeDefinitionId>
            <attributeValueId>
                <name>Unassigned</name>
            </attributeValueId>
        </defectStateAttributeValues>
        <defectStateAttributeValues>
            <attributeDefinitionId>
                <name>OwnerName</name>
            </attributeDefinitionId>
            <attributeValueId>
                <name>etevgul</name>
            </attributeValueId>
        </defectStateAttributeValues>
        <defectStateAttributeValues>
            <attributeDefinitionId>
                <name>Comment</name>
            </attributeDefinitionId>
            <attributeValueId>
                <name></name>
            </attributeValueId>
        </defectStateAttributeValues>
        <defectStateAttributeValues>
            <attributeDefinitionId>
                <name>ExternalReference</name>
            </attributeDefinitionId>
            <attributeValueId>
                <name></name>
            </attributeValueId>
        </defectStateAttributeValues>
        <domain>STATIC_JAVA</domain>
        <filePathname>/user/user-service-impl/src/main/java/com/ericsson/enk/imcp/core/user/service/impl/UserServiceImpl.java</filePathname>
        <firstDetected>2014-04-07T13:47:03.730+03:00</firstDetected>
        <firstDetectedSnapshotId>10014</firstDetectedSnapshotId>
        <functionDisplayName>com.ericsson.enk.imcp.core.user.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.authenticate(com.ericsson.enk.imcp.core.common.domain.Email, java.lang.String)</functionDisplayName>
        <lastDetected>2014-05-12T17:06:44.339+03:00</lastDetected>
        <lastDetectedSnapshotId>10020</lastDetectedSnapshotId>
        <lastFixed>2014-05-09T17:15:27.543+03:00</lastFixed>
        <lastTriaged>2014-04-24T16:21:17.912+03:00</lastTriaged>
        <mergeKey>e4a7c34660b74135e992f11cdfc5b16d</mergeKey>
        <occurrenceCount>1</occurrenceCount>
    </cxp:mergedDefect>
    <latestSnapshotId>10020</latestSnapshotId>
    <streamDefects>
        <cxp:streamDefect>
            <checkerSubcategoryId>
                <checkerName>FORWARD_NULL</checkerName>
                <domain>STATIC_JAVA</domain>
                <subcategory>deref_constant_null</subcategory>
            </checkerSubcategoryId>
            <cid>10549</cid>
            <defectStateAttributeValues>
                <attributeDefinitionId>
                    <name>DefectStatus</name>
                </attributeDefinitionId>
                <attributeValueId>
                    <name>Dismissed</name>
                </attributeValueId>
            </defectStateAttributeValues>
            <defectStateAttributeValues>
                <attributeDefinitionId>
                    <name>Classification</name>
                </attributeDefinitionId>
                <attributeValueId>
                    <name>False Positive</name>
                </attributeValueId>
            </defectStateAttributeValues>
            <defectStateAttributeValues>
                <attributeDefinitionId>
                    <name>Action</name>
                </attributeDefinitionId>
                <attributeValueId>
                    <name>Undecided</name>
                </attributeValueId>
            </defectStateAttributeValues>
            <defectStateAttributeValues>
                <attributeDefinitionId>
                    <name>Fix Target</name>
                </attributeDefinitionId>
                <attributeValueId>
                    <name>Untargeted</name>
                </attributeValueId>
            </defectStateAttributeValues>
            <defectStateAttributeValues>
                <attributeDefinitionId>
                    <name>Severity</name>
                </attributeDefinitionId>
                <attributeValueId>
                    <name>Unspecified</name>
                </attributeValueId>
            </defectStateAttributeValues>
            <defectStateAttributeValues>
                <attributeDefinitionId>
                    <name>Legacy</name>
                </attributeDefinitionId>
                <attributeValueId>
                    <name>False</name>
                </attributeValueId>
            </defectStateAttributeValues>
            <defectStateAttributeValues>
                <attributeDefinitionId>
                    <name>Comment</name>
                </attributeDefinitionId>
                <attributeValueId>
                    <name></name>
                </attributeValueId>
            </defectStateAttributeValues>
            <id>
                <defectTriageId>10345</defectTriageId>
                <defectTriageVerNum>1</defectTriageVerNum>
                <id>21194</id>
                <verNum>2</verNum>
            </id>
            <streamId>
                <name>IMCP_V3-java</name>
            </streamId>
        </cxp:streamDefect>
    </streamDefects>
    <cxp:checkerProperties>
        <subcategoryShortDescription>Explicit null dereferenced</subcategoryShortDescription>
    </cxp:checkerProperties>
</cxp:exportedDefect>
```

As you can see some of them contains namespace frefix and some of them not. I tried to model the xml to pojo to unmurshall but. I couldn't make it to set inner prefixed objects mapped.

Somehow I am thinking of the inner prefixes are being discarded by jaxb.

My root xml element is :

```
package com.ericsson.integration.jira.jaxb.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by olgunkaya on 11.09.2014.
 */
@XmlRootElement (name = "exportedDefect", namespace = "http://export.coverity.com/v7")

public class CoverityDefect implements Serializable {

    private String user;
    private String project;
    private Date timeStamp;
    private MergedDefect mergedDefect;
    private String latestSnapshotId;
    private StreamDefects streamDefects;
    private CheckerProperties checkerProperties;


    public Date getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setTimeStamp(Date timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setProject(String project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    public MergedDefect getMergedDefect() {
        return mergedDefect;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setMergedDefect(MergedDefect mergedDefect) {
        this.mergedDefect = mergedDefect;
    }

    public String getLatestSnapshotId() {
        return latestSnapshotId;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setLatestSnapshotId(String latestSnapshotId) {
        this.latestSnapshotId = latestSnapshotId;
    }

    public StreamDefects getStreamDefects() {
        return streamDefects;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setStreamDefects(StreamDefects streamDefects) {
        this.streamDefects = streamDefects;
    }

    public CheckerProperties getCheckerProperties() {
        return checkerProperties;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setCheckerProperties(CheckerProperties checkerProperties) {
        this.checkerProperties = checkerProperties;
    }
}
```

And one of the failing element is mergedDefect in the xml with the model of :

```
package com.ericsson.integration.jira.jaxb.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by olgunkaya on 11.09.2014.
 */

public class MergedDefect implements Serializable{

    private String checkerName;
    private String checkerSubcategory;
    private String cid;
    private String componentName;
    private List<DefectStateAttributeValues> defectStateAttributeValues;
    private String domain;
    private String filePathname;
    private Date firstDetected;
    private String firstDetectedSnapshotId;
    private String functionDisplayName;
    private Date lastDetected;
    private String lastDetectedSnapshotId;
    private Date lastFixed;
    private Date lastTriaged;
    private String mergeKey;
    private String occurrenceCount;

    public String getCheckerName() {
        return checkerName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setCheckerName(String checkerName) {
        this.checkerName = checkerName;
    }

    public String getCheckerSubcategory() {
        return checkerSubcategory;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setCheckerSubcategory(String checkerSubcategory) {
        this.checkerSubcategory = checkerSubcategory;
    }

    public String getCid() {
        return cid;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setCid(String cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }

    public String getComponentName() {
        return componentName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setComponentName(String componentName) {
        this.componentName = componentName;
    }

    public List<DefectStateAttributeValues> getDefectStateAttributeValues() {
        return defectStateAttributeValues;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setDefectStateAttributeValues(List<DefectStateAttributeValues> defectStateAttributeValues) {
        this.defectStateAttributeValues = defectStateAttributeValues;
    }

    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    public String getFilePathname() {
        return filePathname;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setFilePathname(String filePathname) {
        this.filePathname = filePathname;
    }

    public Date getFirstDetected() {
        return firstDetected;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setFirstDetected(Date firstDetected) {
        this.firstDetected = firstDetected;
    }

    public String getFirstDetectedSnapshotId() {
        return firstDetectedSnapshotId;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setFirstDetectedSnapshotId(String firstDetectedSnapshotId) {
        this.firstDetectedSnapshotId = firstDetectedSnapshotId;
    }

    public String getFunctionDisplayName() {
        return functionDisplayName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setFunctionDisplayName(String functionDisplayName) {
        this.functionDisplayName = functionDisplayName;
    }

    public Date getLastDetected() {
        return lastDetected;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setLastDetected(Date lastDetected) {
        this.lastDetected = lastDetected;
    }

    public String getLastDetectedSnapshotId() {
        return lastDetectedSnapshotId;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setLastDetectedSnapshotId(String lastDetectedSnapshotId) {
        this.lastDetectedSnapshotId = lastDetectedSnapshotId;
    }

    public Date getLastFixed() {
        return lastFixed;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setLastFixed(Date lastFixed) {
        this.lastFixed = lastFixed;
    }

    public Date getLastTriaged() {
        return lastTriaged;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setLastTriaged(Date lastTriaged) {
        this.lastTriaged = lastTriaged;
    }

    public String getMergeKey() {
        return mergeKey;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setMergeKey(String mergeKey) {
        this.mergeKey = mergeKey;
    }

    public String getOccurrenceCount() {
        return occurrenceCount;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setOccurrenceCount(String occurrenceCount) {
        this.occurrenceCount = occurrenceCount;
    }
}
```

Above mergedDefect object always returns null.
I am using below piece for testing.

System.out.println("Creating object from XML");

```
    File file = new File("/Users/olgunkaya/Downloads/atlassian-jira-rest-java-client-890e21ab0a7b/" +
                         "jira-integration/resources/cov-export5653165670998483522.xml");

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    CoverityDefect coverityDefectt = (CoverityDefect) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    System.out.println(coverityDefectt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to an old answer on this post. 
[How to make JAXB unmarshaller to ignore prefixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968399/how-to-make-jaxb-unmarshaller-to-ignore-prefixes)

I have used the same way to remove all prefixes. And now it's working.
Simply to solve such problems. One can extend `XMLFilterImpl` and Override startElement and endElement methods. Then you can modify the `qName` parameters passed to this method. Implementation may vary depending on what you need.

you should also be careful with the POJOs to be used to map the xml to. You may have some Sax Exceptions.

In that case you may need to play around with the xmlfilter implementation a bit.