# UnMarshaling xml string with namespace prefix but no namespaces in the header

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath, jaxb

I receive an XML string like

```
<a:abc>
      <a:xyz>
         <a:a>00185550952</a:a>
         <a:b>MO238620289621365901</a:b>
         <a:c>*17927085</a:c>
         <a:d>awb.20161020121803_3060</a:d>
         <a:e>df64e8ec-d5)7-469)-))71-bbe922f)4f9</a:e>

      </a:xyz>
</a:abc>
```

It doesnt have any namespace or header information.I recieve about 10 million string in this way.What is the effiecient way of parsing an xml string.I tried XPATH but it was to slow.Can jaxb unmarshal this to an jaxb object efficiently

Tried JAXB

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, JAXBException, SAXException, IOException, XMLStreamException {
    String sng = "<a:abc><a:xyz><a:a>00185550952</a:a><a:b>MO238620289621365901</a:b><a:c>*17927085</a:c><a:d>awb.20161020121803_3060</a:d><a:e>df64e8ec-d5)7-469)-))71-bbe922f)4f9</a:e></a:xyz></a:abc";

    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(sng.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));


    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Abc.class);

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
}
```

**Abc.Java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "abc")
public class Abc {

    @XmlElement(name = "xyz", required = true)
    public Xyz xyz;
    public Xyz getXyz() {
        return xyz;
    }
    public void setXyz(Xyz xyz) {
        this.xyz = xyz;
    }
}**

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "xyz")
public class Xyz {
    @XmlElement(name = "a")
    public String a;
    @XmlElement(name = "b")
    public String b;
    @XmlElement(name = "c")
    public String c;
    @XmlElement(name = "d")
    public String d;
    @XmlElement(name = "e")
    public String e;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public String getE() {
        return e;
    }

    public void setE(String e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

}
```

**Exception**

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 8; The prefix "a" for element "a:abc" is not bound.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:578)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:264)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at 
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 8; The prefix "a" for element "a:abc" is not bound.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
    ... 4 more

Comment: For large XML files, use SAX.

Comment: Why don't you try it? Then you can check whether the performance is sufficient enough for you.

Comment: Yeah i would like to try.But i need help in parsing xml string without namespaces information.

Comment: Ok, so you tried it with XPath, that worked but was too slow. Then you tried it with JAXB and it doesn't work. You should show us the code (of the JAXB parsing). Without it is impossible to help. If there is any error message, please show this exact message including the stack trace.

Comment: Can you please show the class `A`, too? Then we got a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Posted jaxb classes.My problem was i dont have namespace information on my xml

Comment: When you run the code, is there an error/exception? If yes, then post the full error message including stack trace.

Comment: For future questions you should ask all these questions yourself beforehand. Your question should contain all this information from the beginning. Otherwise it is too time consuming. You caught me on a good day. I'm usually not so handholding.

Comment: Here is an exact duplicate of your question including a solution with a SAX filter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968399/how-to-make-jaxb-unmarshaller-to-ignore-prefixes

Comment: Thank you @vanje, it worked