# XML Parsing Broken after JDK11/EAP7 upgrade

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jboss-eap-7

I'm upgrading an app from `EAP6.4/JDK8 -> EAP7.2/JDK11` and my XML parsing doesn't seem to be working the same. Before the upgrade I was able to parse the following XML into an annotated object.

No compile or runtime errors, app deploys.

If I remove the preceding `app:` from the XML it'll convert, else everything is `null`. Is there a way to unmarshall this xml while ignoring the namespace `app:`?

**Output**

```
XML{id='null', time=null, type='null', description='null', time=null}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<app:exampleXML xmlns:app="http://www.example.com/schemas/schema">
<app:id>app-id</app:id>
<app:time>2020-06-05T13:17:00.899Z</app:time>
<app:type>test</app:type>
<app:description>Test</app:description>
</app:exampleXML>
```

**Object**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.UUID;

@XmlRootElement(name = "exampleXML", namespace="http://www.example.com/schemas/schema")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XML {
    public static final int DESCRIPTION_LENGTH = 4000;

    @XmlElement(name = "id", required = true)
    private String id;


    @XmlElement(name = "time", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(InstantXmlAdapter.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = InstantJsonSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = InstantJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Instant time;

    @XmlElement(name = "type", required = true)
    private CheckpointLevel type;

    @XmlElement(name = "description")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CDATAXmlAdapter.class)
    private String description;
```

**EDIT:**

I'm implementing `jakarta` in my gradle build to account for the lack of jaxb in jdk11.

```
implementation "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2"
implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2"
```

Comment: How is it broken? Note that JAXB is not included anymore in the JDK after JDK 8. See [JAXB on Java 9, 10, 11 and beyond](https://jesperdj.com/2018/09/30/jaxb-on-java-9-10-11-and-beyond/) (blogpost by me).

Comment: @Jesper Just added my output. Seems that the parsing can't find the elements when `app:` is in the xml and sets the data to null `XML{id='null', time=null, type='null', description='null', time=null}`

Comment: It might be of interest to know how the unmarshaller / JAXB system is instanciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make JAXB unmarshaller to ignore prefixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968399/how-to-make-jaxb-unmarshaller-to-ignore-prefixes)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from version 9 JAXB was removed from JDK. You need to add them as separate dependencies. If you are using Maven or Gradle you can use Maven repository for that:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```